# Silverlight apply implicit style that sets other style

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a TextBox Style with a Key defined in external resource dictionary file, then I'm trying to define a new implicit TextBox Style that sets "Keyed" style from resource dictionary, so basically I want to seet the style from resource dictionary as a default for TextBox, but I can't remove Key from there, because it is used by other code.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="FileWithNiceTextBoxStyle.xaml"/>
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource NiceTextBoxStyle}"/>
</Style>
```

However this doesn't work, and result in Visual Studio crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `BasedOn` attribute:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="GlobalTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource GlobalTextBox}"></Style>
...
<TextBox Text="I have pink background"/>
```